# Excel - pass an array into a function

Tags: arrays, excel, array-formulas, named-ranges

On one sheet in my file I have a number of arrays defined as named ranges. One another sheet I'd like to use a drop down, or something similar to select the name of one of the named range and have the data/contents of that named range populate a range on the second sheet. Is this possible **WITHOUT** VBA? Is there an array formula that will do this?

One, not entirely elegant, method that I've thought of is using the `index` function and copy this within a range of cells equivalent in size to the size of the largest named range. Something like:

```
=INDEX(range_1,ROW(),COLUMN())
```

This requires me to be able to pass the name of a named range into a function though. Is this possible?

Answers to either or both of these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Without that, the only other way I can think to do this is using a brute force, `offset` look up, which I'd prefer not to do.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are the named ranges all of the same size?

Comment: No they are all different sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Indirect` might do what you want it to.

In Sheet1 I created 3 named ranges:

[image]

Then in Sheet2, I

1) Put these names in Column A

2) Used a data validation list linked to column A to place a name in a cell (C2)

3) Used the array formula `{=INDIRECT(C2)}` (accepted with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`) in the cells that I wanted to hold the array (C4:E5)

[image]

When C2 is changed via the drop-down, the array is automatically changed:

[image]

Comment: Can this be used for ranges or different size?

Comment: Just answered my own question. That's brilliant John. I appreciate your help.